# Regex for capturing repeated groups Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, transformation, regex-group

I have some test data in the following format -

```
"lorem ipsum <img src='some_url' class='some_class' /> lorem ipsum <img src='some_url' class='some_class' /> ipsum <img src='some_url' class='some_class' />"
```

Now, my goal is to identify all the image tags along with their respective source urls and css classes and store them together with the remaining text in an ordered array like -

```
["lorem ipsum", {imageObject1}, "lorem ipsum", {imageObject2}, "ipsum", {imageObject3}]
```

Now for this I tried to create a sample regex

```
var regex = /(.*(<img\s+src=['"](.+)['"]\s+(class=['"].+['"])?\s+\/>)+?.*)+/ig
```

Now when I try this regex with the sample text i am getting -

```
regex.exec(sample_text) => [0:"lorem ipsum <img src='some_url1' class='some_class1' /> lorem ipsum <img src='some_url2' class='some_class2' /> ipsum <img src='some_url3' class='some_class3' />"
1:"lorem ipsum <img src='some_url1' class='some_class1' /> lorem ipsum <img src='some_url2' class='some_class2' /> ipsum <img src='some_url3' class='some_class3' />"
2:"<img src='some_url3' class='some_class3' />"
3:"some_url3"
4:"class='some_class3'"]
```

How in javascript can I transform the sample html text 
into an array of tagged html objects with their attributes.

Comment: You need to use `String.prototype.match()`

Comment: well it's a bit complicated you could try to use a regex inside `.split()` to split the input to the form of your desired output. in addition you could then just run your regex over each part of the resulting array to extract your desired data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1682509

Comment: well.. maybe you even want to use DOM operations to do this. i don't see a reason as to why you are even trying to mess with html through regex

Comment: I wanted to create dynamic pdfs with PDFMake.js and they require document object definitions in a strict format as I specified above so that is why I wanted to try and parse the HTML content with the help of regex. 
split seems a good option to try I completely forgot about this one, but I believe DOMParser would be a good fit for my task here so I will also try it for once

Comment: use DOM operations for that. seriously. regex is the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

[Do not use regular expressions to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1682509). Use a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to parse the string and then CSS queries to get the images from the DOM, it will be much more reliable and easier to read.

```
var html = "lorem ipsum <img src='some_url' class='some_class' /> lorem ipsum <img src='some_url' class='some_class' /> ipsum <img src='some_url' class='some_class' />"

var nodes = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html").body.childNodes
```

That will get you almost what you wanted (just some empty Text nodes you can filter out).

Or do something a little bit more accurate like this in case you don't have just images and text in the HTML:

```
var images = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html").querySelectorAll("img")
var array = new Map([...images].map(img => [img.previousSibling.nodeValue, img]))
```